# Change class value based on element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Slap me if I am going about this wrong, I am quite the beginner.

Here is my setup, which is very similar visually to Outlook's UI I guess.

Left pane (floating div) contains a list of  containers you can click on (like emails). Right hand pane contains a set of non-visible  containers that should become visible when their class is changed to a different css class.

I'm trying to set it up where if you click on the element in the left pane, it then performs an onclick javascript action (stored in an external .js file) that toggles the right div's class value between two css classes.

The onclick in the left pane div passes $_row['uniqueID'] to the function. That is the uniquely incremented column name. It is also the ID value of the right pane 's.

Putting this altogether, can someone direct me on how to do this?

**left pane...**

```
<div onclick=\"toggleMenu('".$row['uniqueIdentifier'],"'); \">
```

**right pane...**

```
<div id=".$row['uniqueIdentifier']," class=\"mL\">
```

**css...**

```
div.mL {display:none;}
div.mL.active {display:block;}
```

Comment: why do you escape class names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function toggleMenu(div){
    $('#'+div).addClass('active');
}
```

jQuery has `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods.

I think that's what you're after, let me know if not.

Comment: Thanks! Gave me the syntax. I was actually very close in my own work, just missing a few characters.

`function toggleMenu(div){
    $('#'+div).toggleClass('active');
}` seems to work well

Answer (score 1):

By not changing too much code I suggest doing this :

```
div.mL {display:none;}
div.mLactive {display:block;}
```

I erased the dot, so u have now 2 different classes.
So on clicking you just change the class of the div with the correct id to mLactive.

In Jquery this canbe done with $(#'theid').addClass('mLactive');
This only adds the new class. You also want to remove the previous class with $(#'theid').removeClass('mL');

Another way : $(#'theid').attr( "class" , "mLactive"  ); Which doesn't require to remove the previous class. Your choice. Another advantage of this method is that javascript has a method to do that which doesn't require Jquery.

Jquery has also the easy options $(#'theid').show(); and $(#'theid').hide() btw.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I believe `function toggleMenu(div){
    $('#'+div).toggleClass('active');
}` will do it but the above is good to know as I can apply that to other items. Now just need to figure out how to only allow one div to be toggled to the active class at a time. That is a separate issue though that I will investigate.

Comment: You could do something like : if click, get the element with the active class. If no element was found, you can toggle an element. But if an element was found with the active class, you do nothing. Working with disabled buttons is probably a nicer way, but will need more code.